# Interaction with view behind SlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I use the library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel to add a sliding up menu.

But someone know how can I make interraction with view behind SlidingUpPanel?

In my case, I have a map behind,  the slidingUpPanel is transparent but it stop the interaction with the map (and I can't move my map inside sliding_layout).

Maybe it's a configuration problem?

Maybe someone have à solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the map is in your slidingUpPanel then you have to try with setDragView method of the umano library which you are using. But if your mapView is in the MainView then nothing to do with that. it will be free to do anything there once the sliding is collapsed.